# How do you call the latest date from existing table?

Tags: sql, date

I have a table called `tbl.date`, I have a column `LAST_UPDATE`. I need to fetch the latest update date. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM [tbl.date]
WHERE [LAST_UPDATE] = --I need an SQL system code to go in here to fetch the latest update date
```

Comment: You could/should order by LAST_UPDATE desc and add LIMIT 1 to the query... This way you'll have only the latest record.

Comment: Why cant you select max(Last_Update) from tbl.date?

Comment: Please tag what DBMS you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: The first information you should give out is the dbms you are using.  The solution vary for different dbms.  It's useless if we give you solution to the wrong dbms.

Comment: I've edited your question, please check it, and I've posted a few examples of how to do this, the 2nd one being valid in many cases regardless of the DBMS you are using. Still helpful for you to tag properly though.

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server and if LAST_UPDATE column is a Date type

```
SELECT * FROM tbl.date
WHERE LAST_UPDATE = (SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE) FROM tbl.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just `SELECT TOP 1` and then `ORDER BY` `DESC`

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [tbl.date]
ORDER BY [LAST_UPDATE] DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE) AS LastUpdate
FROM [tbl.date]
```

OR

```
SELECT [LAST_UPDATE]
FROM [tbl.date]
ORDER BY [LAST_UPDATE] DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using TOP WITH TIES:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
    FROM  tbl.date
    ORDER BY [LAST_UPDATE] DESC;
```

It returns all the records from your table that matches the most recent update date.